# I am trying to remove items from a duplicated list based uppon items from another list (inside a loop). error: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is my code:

```
check_list = ['a', 'aaafa', 'bbb', 'agaa']
stock = ['f', 'g', 'z']
stock2 = stock

for i in range(len(stock)):
    for j in range(len(check_list)):

        if len(stock) > 0 and stock[i].upper() in check_list[j].upper():
            print(stock2)
            stock2.remove(stock[i])
            print(stock2)

        else:
            print('a')
```

My `prints` output the following:

```
a
['f', 'g', 'z']
['g', 'z']
a
['g', 'z']
['z']
```

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I understand where this error occurs and why, but the interpreter says that the error is here:

```
if len(stock) > 0 and stock[i].upper() in check_list[j].upper():
```

Idk how to fix it.

Comment: Because you assigned `stock2 = stock` any changes to stock2 will be reflected back to stock. When you remove an item from stock2 in the if statement you are also removing the item from `stock`. You should instead use `stock2 = stock.copy()`.

Comment: Remember that stock and stock2 are the same object (lists are mutable objects, assignment just bind a new variable name to the same object in memory).

Comment: The error is exactly where the interpreter says it is. The mistake is explained in the above comments.

Answer (score 0):

Why it happens: You assign

```
stock2 = stock
```

but this does not *copy* `stock`, it just adds another reference to it. Your loop runs in `range(len(stock))` and that range object is not modified/updated when you modify `stock` by removing stuff. Thus, `stock[i]` will be out of range as soon as you `remove`.

Howto fix:

I did not try it out, by you could

```
stock2 = list(stock)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, lists are assigned by reference.

When you do `stock2 = stick` both variables will refer to the same object; when you remove items from that object via `stock2` they will no longer be in the list by either reference.

Instead, make a copy of the list, eg `stock2 = list(stock)`